# Installing MySQL Connector/C++ or MySQL++ on windows

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying for hours to get either of these working and linked in with Visual Studio (2012 Express version) but there is no consistency with installation instructions.

[**Site 1**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html), [**Site 2**](http://r3dux.org/2010/11/how-to-use-mysql-connectorc-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-windows/), [**Site 3**](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1338576740-Using-MySQL-Connector-C%2B%2B-with-Visual-Studio-2010), [**Site 4**](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,249344,249344), [**Site 5**](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html), [**Site 6**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html).

It is infuriating to say the least. Some say these folders exist when they don't, other mention dependencies that others do not, some say include these directories and others say include those; its ridiculous how hard this is.

**Does anybody know how to install a MySQL/C++ library? And be able to give clear instructions on how to do so? because, for me at least, the answer so far is no.**

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problems you're having?  The "Site1" link provides an msi installer for Windows which should install what you need. Are you having problems when you try to build? Additionally, you may want to switch to the Community Edition of Visual Studio since there are no longer restrictions on its usage.

Comment: After running the `.msi` there is little to no information on what to do next in order to get it setup on Visual Studio. I've tried numerous Include Directories and such but not even the examples will run

Comment: Did you follow [Chapter 3 Installing MySQL Connector/C++ from a Binary Distribution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html)?  Incidentally, this link does not imply support for vs2012.  Additionally, did you read the _readme_ file that gets installed?  If none of that works, you may be forced to use [ODBC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yb4e48(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I had crash problems at runtime when using BLOBs with the c++ connector. My recommendation would be to use the c library and build your own simple c++ RAII wrappers.

Comment: I think I'll try with ODBC, thanks.